# Convergence Test Validation

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Is the convergence test approach to verify the series's convergence properly used? Please help me validate this answer.
[image]

Comment: In $b_{n+1}$ you wrote $(n+1)^2 - (n+1)$ when it should have been $(n+1)^2 + (n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your answer is incorrect. In fact, your series turns out to be divergent, I'll elaborate.

Let's address your mistake: the problem is in your limit computation, you claim that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n = \lim_{n\to \infty} n\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - n = \lim_{n\to \infty} n(\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1) $

Although you are correct that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1 =0$ however this will lead to $$lim_{n\to \infty} \ n(\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1) = \infty \cdot 0$$ which is an indeterminate form.

Notice that you can rewrite the limit as: $$lim_{n\to \infty} \ n(\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1) = lim_{n\to \infty} \ \frac {\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1}{\frac 1n}$$ and now instead of getting $\infty \cdot 0$ we get $lim_{n\to \infty} \ \frac {\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1}{\frac 1n} = \frac 00$. This is useful because we can now apply L'Hôpital's rule so let's calculate the derivates: $$(\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1)' = \frac 12 (1 + \frac 1n)^{-\frac 12}(-\frac{1}{n^2}) $$ and $$(\frac 1n)' = -\frac{1}{n^2}$$ so we get $$lim_{n\to \infty} \ \frac {\sqrt{1 + \frac 1n} - 1}{\frac 1n} = lim_{n\to \infty} \ \frac{\frac 12 (1 + \frac 1n)^{-\frac 12}(-\frac{1}{n^2})}{-\frac{1}{n^2}} = lim_{n\to \infty} \ \frac 12 (1 + \frac 1n)^{-\frac 12} = \frac 12 $$
Notice the limit is not $0$ so we can't use the Alternating Series Test. However, the limit is not $0$ so probably the Divergence Test will be useful here!

Notice that the only thing missing in our limit computation is $(-1)^n$ if we plug this missing term in our result we get: $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n (\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n) = \frac {(-1)^n}{2}$$ and you can see that this limit does not exist since it's either $\frac 12$ or $-\frac 12$. Therefore, by the Divergence Test, the series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (\sqrt{n^2 + n} - n)$ diverges.